# Android-How to transfer a file via wifi direct?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, wifi-direct

I want to make an app which sends a file via Wi-Fi direct. I followed the instruction in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) and learned how to discover and connect to a device but I have some problem with the code which is used to transfer files.

One of those parts:

```
InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
```

I can't understand what does this code do.

Or:

```
copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
```

The problem is Android Studio couldn't find `copyFile` method.(Is this a custom method??)

Please help me with these 2 problems and also give a detailed info for the first one.

Comment: You should program that function your self. Reading chunks of bytes in a loop from the input stream and writing them to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should see WiFiDirectDemo project, there is the already working example there (sending an image file from gallery):
[WiFiDirectDemo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/)

and here's the copy file method:

```
public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```